# How would one integrate $\sin\left(\pi t^2\right)$ from 0 to 1?

Tags: calculus, integration

I got this problem on my final exam and was completely lost on how to solve it. It's pretty short as problems go but it was surprisingly difficult. Does u-sub work here?

$$ \int_{0}^{1}\sin(\pi t^2) dt $$

Thanks for your help!

---

**EDIT:**

I'd appreciate if a mod could delete this. I appear to have remembered the problem incorrectly and it would be impossible to solve using things learned in Calc 1.

Comment: There is no way to do this. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+sin(pi+x%5E2)+from+0+to+1

Comment: Is it in $dt$ ?

Comment: @ZacharySelk Then why would they put it on the test? Perhaps I didn't remember the problem correctly.

Comment: @Euler_Salter Yes it should be. Sorry for the typo.

Comment: Was it a Calculus course or a Complex Variable course?

Comment: @Euler_Salter I'm taking Calc 1. I'm starting to think I copied the problem down wrong!

Comment: @Someguy probably you did are you sure it wasn't $sin(\pi t)^2$?

Comment: Was the test multiple choice? Maybe the purpose was to be able to spot the reasonable answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're in the range $[0,1]$ you can deal with Taylor Series

$$\sin(\pi t^2) = \sum_{k = 0}^{+\infty} \frac{(-1)^k (\pi t^2)^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}$$

Hence

$$\int_0^1 \sum_{k = 0}^{+\infty} \frac{(-1)^k (\pi t^2)^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!} = \sum_{k = 0}^{+\infty} \frac{(-1)^k \pi^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}\int_0^1 t^{2(2k+1)}\ \text{d}t$$

The integral is trivial and you get at the end

$$\sum_{k = 0}^{+\infty} \frac{(-1)^k \pi^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!} \frac{1}{4k+3}$$

If you are in search of numerical approximation then you can develop the series term by term:

$$\frac{\pi}{3} - \frac{\pi^3}{42} + \frac{\pi^5}{1212} - \frac{\pi^7}{10900} + \ldots $$

Numerical result:

$$0.5048545941136863...$$

Comment: The series of pies look cool and the method here is widely applicable, so +1

Comment: @SimpleArt Thank you so much! ^^

Answer (score 1):

This is likely asking for a numerical approximation or you didn't write it correctly. The exact answer is $\frac{\operatorname{S}(\sqrt{2})}{\sqrt{2}}$ where $\operatorname{S}(x)$ is the Sine Integral function, which is cannot be represented in terms of elementary functions (the basic functions you'll see in a calculus class). A numerical approximation is $0.504855...$

Comment: There is no exact answer for that integral, since the Sine Integral itself is not an exact answer for the integral of $\sin(x)/x$.

Comment: @AlanTuring what definition of "exact" are you using? The Sine Integral ***IS*** the exact integral because it is ***defined*** to be that way. Do you mean you don't like it because it lacks an arguably "simple" power series? It does have one, and "simple" is really a matter of perspective. Same situation as the logarithm... We often DEFINE the logarithm as the integral of $1/x$. We then calculate it using handheld calculators, which use the power series expansion. I fail to see the difference, other than the logarithm is coming considered an "elementary function", as my post notes

Comment: Wrong. The Si(z) function is nothing but the integral itself (bounded). It's not the PRIMITIVE.

Comment: @AlanTuring so you define "primitive" and "exact"  to be just the elementary functions and don't ever use anything else? That's awfully restrictive, and isn't necessarily good. Studying special functions is a big and important topic in math, as it helps us finds better series expansions, connections between functions, etc. Expressing these relations using function notation is much easier than remembering all the potential cases of the integral forms.

Comment: @AlanTuring if you really do exclude everything that isn't considered "elementary"  (which itself lacks a great definition... It's just a few types of functions that have a nice algebraic structure) then sure,  you can argue my post is a tautology. Doesn't mean it's not *exact* or that's it's *wrong* though,  merely tautological, and I wholeheartedly disagree with you on it being a tautology. I reiterate my example with the logarithm, which is defined in terms of an integral.

Comment: I do not see the point in this arguing.  Both viewpoints are perfectly fine and align fine with the question at hand.

Comment: What I am saying is this: take this integral

$$\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\ \text{d}x$$

And..oh look! We are not able to integrate it. So let's define it as $$\text{Si}(x)$$

Et voilà. Does this lead us to some result? Nope, it's just a mere definition. That is not the primitive of that integral, because it simply does not exist. And your answer is not defining an "exact" result because the "exactness" of that result is circular, it's self-exact. It cannot even be wrong since it's a definition.

That is my point.

Comment: As an argument for why such a definition is nevertheless useful: Since it's already got that name attached to it, one can quickly discover (by Google or Wikipedia) that quite a few approximations are known for Si(x). For instance, Abromowitz and Stegun lists the Taylor series, but it includes [asymptotic series and rational approximants](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_233.htm) for Si(x). Additionally, the DLMF has an entire [chapter](http://dlmf.nist.gov/6) devoted to integrals in this category. So, if nothing else, knowing about Si(x) gives an entry point to a ton of literature.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking at [Fresnel's integral](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_integral), particularly,

$$S(x)=\int_0^x\sin(t^2)\ dt$$